# Koin - Is there any way to add a class with default constructor to a Koin module with some annotation?

Tags: kotlin, koin

Is it possible to add some class with **default constructor** to a Koin module in runtime using some annotation? I know that Koin does not use reflection and it is good but it many cases I only want to add a class with default constructor as a singleton to Koin module. It would be nice if it can be done using some annotation.

I tried using **reflection** and find all classes with some specific annotation and use **bind** like below to add each clazz to the Koin module:

```
single { clazz.newInstance() } bind clazz.kotlin
```

But it was not applicable. Since `clazz.newInstance()` return `Any` and does not match `clazz` type.

Comment: I am not really understand the need for that. Why don't you just add it by hand to a module?

Comment: With so many classes it yields to something tedious and error prone

Comment: Hm. I disagree a bit as you have your module definition in one place this way. Anyway have you tried to just cast your single? -> `clazz.newInstance() as RealClass`

Comment: I cannot write `as RealClass` at runtime.